# Jquery AJAX Post: 500 (Internal Server Error)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services, google-chrome-extension

I am trying post a string to web service but I am getting this error (Google Chrome Extension Project):

> jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4 POST http://localhost:49242/Service.asmx/test
>   500 (Internal Server Error)

Here is my ajax code:

```
var data = {};
data.param1 = words[0];

$.ajax({
    data: JSON.stringify({ 'data': data.param1 }),
    dataType: 'application/json',
    url: 'http://localhost:49242/Service.asmx/test',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
    },
    failure: function (errMsg) {
        alert(errMsg);
    }
});
```

My service:

```
[WebMethod]

[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = System.Web.Script.Services.ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string test(string param1) {
    return param1;
}
```

I am working on this problem about 3 days. Can you help me ?

By the way, I have a question. I am posting json variable to service with ajax(like you see), but service returning xml value. Is there a problem or `[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = System.Web.Script.Services.ResponseFormat.Json)]` this code block solving problem?

Comment: write `json` in dataType

Comment: Thanks but it didn't worked.

Comment: did you check your url is working on which are you posting data ?

Comment: Try not stringfying your data? data: { param1: 'yourval'}

Comment: Sorry but why do you delete your last post?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error come from your data parameter. Stringify `data` object instead of `{ 'data': data.param1 }` :

```
var data = {};
data.param1 = words[0];

$.ajax({
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    dataType: 'application/json',
    url: 'http://localhost:49242/Service.asmx/test',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
    },
    failure: function (errMsg) {
        alert(errMsg);
    }
});
```

Your stringifyed data will result in `{"param1":"Words"}`, then your service should be able to bind the `param1` parameter.

Comment: Thank you very much it worked. But i posted service "blah" string but service returned [object Object]. Why?

Comment: Chrome and I took care of problem.This worked:  var data = response.hasOwnProperty("d") ? response.d : response;
            alert(data);

Comment: Happy to hear about it :)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this type of error on AJAX post response. I was spending too much time behind this issue and finally I caught it.

It throws a 500 internal error because the AJAX response has a lot of content from the server so it returns a timeout of execution.

So I just added the line below and it's working fine.

```
Page.Server.ScriptTimeout = 300;
```

Comment: Where did you add that line? [@Belle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8019185/belle) had a question ([attempted to edit your post as a reply](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17723040))

Comment: I am calling ajax function with the URL of page "emailapi.aspx". In this situation i am getting that error but when i have added **Page.Server.ScriptTimeout = 300;** into emailapi.aspx. it's works fine.